Amplifying audio on piezo buzzer
I want to output an audio signal from a uC to a piezo buzzer. I first tried the obvious solution with a single transistor in series with the buzzer, but at 3V the sound volume was a bit too low.
The accepted answer to a similar question was to use a full bridge driver, with phase inverted signals.
It says only to use the full bridge design with waveforms that are either high or low at any given time (a square wave,) so as to not create any temporary short circuit conditions. That might become a problem when trying to play back audio samples, where the signal will be all over the place.
I tried building the same circuit for my own application, but I added R5 and R6 as current limiting resistors to mitigate the short circuit issue:

The problem is that even at relatively low values on R5 and R6, the sound volume drops to similar levels as with my original single transistor design.
Without R5 and R6 the circuit consumes 100-110 mA, according to my DMM. With 30 ohm resistors for R5 and R6 it's about 80-90 mA.
What values on R5 and R6 could be considered "safe"? Do I really need these extra resistors for sample playback? Could I design the circuit in any other way?

Which piezo that is, can you give a part number of the device you bought? Also what are you trying to play, analog audio from DAC output or digital audio in the form of PWM or PDM? From where the audio comes from and how it is converted to inverted signal?

Unfortunately I don't have the exact specs of the piezo element, except that it's passive and rated for 5V. I don't know what mA it's rated for. If it matters to the question let's assume 20 mA and base calculations on that. Then I can adjust values when I get a piezo with known specs.
The audio comes directly from two ATtiny85 pins. It's a PWM signal, where one output (/BUZZ) is inverted.

I guess I answered my own question. Since the uC outputs a PWM signal, which is basically a square wave, a short circuit condition would never occur. Right?

No, it should not occur - except on each transition of the PWM signals because it takes time for the BJT transistors to turn on and off. Why don't you just remove the transistors and connect the BUZZ and /BUZZ signals directly to the piezo - they already are a H bridge?

I can. But sound volume gets very low. IIRC the ATtiny85 pins will only source/sink 5 or 10 mA with a 3V supply.

Not really - the pin will output much more, it's just rated to be within some given DC voltage specs at some given current. 40mA is absolute maximum and DC ratings go up to 20mA, and the piezo is not a DC load. Try buffering the PWM pins with strong CMOS buffers to drive the piezo. What PWM freqency there is? Also, do consider higher voltage for the piezo, or getting a better piezo that works loud enough at 3V and driven from PWM outputs directly.

In your circuit Q1 & Q3 form a current path that is present between the supply rail +3.3v & GND when input signal is zero.  Same for Q2 & Q4.  This is a major problem.
Instead, try swapping the positions of Q1 & Q3 (ditto for Q2 & Q4).  No need for R5 & R6, in fact no need for any resistors at all, so replace all resitors with a wire.
The new circuit forms two BJT voltage follower stages, each driving one side of the load (piezo buzzer).  Drive the bases of one side with the original signal, drive the other side with the inverse of the original signal.
This avoids the current path from +3.3V to GND, and has the advantage of greater voltage swing than the more usual half-bridge (which avoids the dc-blocking capacitor when using single power supply rails).
For greater current gain try a Sziklai rather than Darlington configuration, this saves one Vbe drop.  Eg:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/689296/341959
A design method for a full-bridge amplifier is provided here:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/688822/341959
UPDATE #1:
Since the original question mentioned play-back of audio samples, I have updated the answer with the schematic below, which is an improvement on the previous answer.  The improvement is done by the biasing string on each BJT voltage follower, which is a primitive way of reducing the cross-over distortion that my previous answer would have.  For the purposes of illustrating the concept, the signals BUZZ_1 & BUZZ_2 are AC coupled to the drivers via C1 & C2, the value of these will set the lower cut-off frequency (must be sufficiently large to ensure the lowest frequencies of interest are passed through to the speaker).

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
UPDATE #2:
A further improvement is shown below.  The diodes in the bias strings have been replaced with transistors.  This change results in much less current required to drive the input node, which means the AC coupling capacitors can be much smaller.  Furthermore, the cross-over distortion is significantly reduced.

UPDATE #3:
To ensure each voltage buffer is biased at the supply mid-point, add a string of resistors to the input node of each buffer, one up to the pos rail, the other down to the neg rail.  220kΩ should be adequate.
